# Cannot install while still directory is still in $PATH

Tags: command-line, software-installation, error-handling

While installing OH MY POSH, these two errors appear, although the second one is a bug([reported](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/issues/4457)). I have added the`/usr/local/bin`  directory in $PATH in ~/.zshrc and showing while echoed. I cannot understand why it is telling me that the installation directory not in the $PATH.

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu, `sudo` will set PATH to its `secure_path` (although by default that contains /usr/local/bin already) - what does `sudo zsh -c 'echo $PATH'` return?

Comment: @steeldriver This is returned: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`. Using previously mentioned paths like `/usr/bin` returns same result.

Comment: Use `bash`, not `zsh` might help.

Comment: Please do not post photos of the terminal but copy and paste the content into a code block. This gives way better readability.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because you are running a bash script with `zsh`. Please always follow instructions when installing. You are running this as root, with `sudo`, which is a horrible idea (you really don't want to blindly pipe downloaded shell scripts into a root shell) and not what the  [installation instructions](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/linux) suggest.

And then, you are running a bash script with `zsh`. This is what causes the error. You can reproduce it with this little code snippet, which is just a slightly simplified version of the relevant code from the `install.sh` script:

```bash
p="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
install_dir="/usr/local/bin"
  good=$(
        IFS=":"
        for path in $p; do
        if [ "${path%/}" = "${install_dir}" ]; then
            printf 1
            break
        fi
        done
    )

    if [ "${good}" != "1" ]; then
        echo "Installation directory ${install_dir} is not in your \$PATH"
    else
      echo "Dir $install_dir FOUND!"
    fi
```

If you run that with bash, it works as expected and prints that the directory was found:

```
$ bash ~/scripts/foo.sh
Dir /usr/local/bin FOUND!
```

However, running it with `zsh` returns the error you see:

```
$ zsh ~/scripts/foo.sh
Installation directory /usr/local/bin is not in your $PATH
```

That's because in zsh, the unquoted `$p` is not split on IFS unless the SH_WORD_SPLIT option is set via `setopt shwordsplit` or it is explicitly requested with `$=p` or `${=p}`. So the string comparison on `for path in $p; ...`  is being executed exactly once with the whole of `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin` on the LHS<sup>1</sup>.

So, run the script with the shell it was written for and it should work as expected. If you are 100% confident it is safe, you can use `sudo` so it is installed in the default `/usr/local/bin` directory:

```
curl -s https://ohmyposh.dev/install.sh | bash -s
```

Or, to be a bit safer, just install it for your user with

```
curl -s https://ohmyposh.dev/install.sh | bash -s -- -d ~/bin
```

---

<sup>1. using `path` as a user variable in zsh would be a no-no as well - as in csh, `path` is an array version of `PATH` and assigning to it will break subsequent command lookups - although in this context the effect would be local to the `$(...)` command substitution.</sup>